# Chrome Search looks weird?

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

I am running windows 8.1. I am sure that Google search doesn't look like this.
Please tell me the steps to bring back search to its original state.

Small thumbnails and it looks exactly like this:

[image]

Comment: I looked at the image and it isn't clear what the issue is.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Try search over HTTPS

Comment: @fixer1234 the looks is becoming a big issue to me. That isn't the Google search I was used to. The appearance seems odd. Looks like it's the old version of google search.

Comment: Another thing is, I can't see Meta tags whenever I search. Is this a spyware issue? Browser hijacking?

Comment: What's the Globe icon at the top right? Is it for modifying UA?

Comment: I don't really know. I am not the owner of that image. I just want to show what is exactly happening to my Google searches. And that image I got from the web is fully identical to my issue.@ProtoAES256

Comment: Did you get this fixed? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your current search looks different because it's a "Custom Search Engine".  `www.google.com/cse?hl=eng&source=hp&q=test`

= google.com/(custom search engine) (host language = english) (source=HP) (Query="test")

My best guess is that you searched from somewhere OTHER THAN

- google.com search box
- chrome browsers "super bar"

Administrators of CSE's are able to "customize" their search results.

Strait from a google search of ("what is google.com /cse") >>>

> Google Custom Search (formerly known as Google Co-op) is a platform provided by Google that allows web developers to feature specialized information in web searches, refine and categorize queries and create customized search engines, based on Google Search.

Comment: If your able to connect to google.com without using SSL (NOT using HTTPS), I would deffinetly recommend enabling SSL/TLS within your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change any settings in Chrome, or did you recently install some theme extensions? I know this happened to me a while back when I screwed something up in the settings of Chrome but I know Chrome also allows for themes to be added.  You may want to reset your settings for Chrome or delete your latest extension (if you just installed some).  If none of that works you may try to reinstall Chrome. EDIT: To reset settings go to the three lines on top left > Settings > Scroll down > Advanced settings > all the way at the bottom there is a reset option.

Comment: Tried everything, man. Reset chrome. Reinstalled chrome. But none of them worked. Is this a spyware/malware issue?