# Google search results look different, unable to access Bing.com. All browsers

Tags: browser, search

I'm running Windows 10 Pro X64. This problem is affecting Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE.

First the Google.com issue. This is what it looks like. Google Results. Notice the GOOOOOGLE from the bottom is gone. Also when I search google, it seems to sign me out. As you can see it says I'm not signed in. But I've found that as it loads, it says I'm signed in, then loads a new web page. Someone else had the [same](https://superuser.com/questions/889991/chrome-search-looks-weird#new-answer) issue, but never seemed to fix it.

The second issue is Bing.com. When I try to access it, it half loads. And when I search from it it doesn't really do anything. As seen here, when I go to Bing.com and here, when I search for "test".

The issue seems to be that it's using a CSE, google custom search engine. But it's happening computer wide.

- When I go to Bing.com

[image]

- When I search "test"

[image]

- When I search "test" on google. Entire page.

[image]

- When I search "test" on google. Default zoom.

[image]

This is what I have done

- Ran Malwarebytes, nothing found.
- Ran Adwcleaner, it found .END in /C and Snapdo.com Both were removed.
- Ran JRT, it found nothing.
- Ran SAS, it found nothing.
- Checked Change / Remove programs, nothing to be found there that shouldn't be.

I'm not really sure what to do now other than wiping my system...really rather not.

Comment: Whats the problem with search in google, I too get the same results (almost same) for the 'test' keyword.

Comment: A good next step would be turning on Wireshark while trying to visit these sites and see if you can find any clues in the packet captures.

Comment: Have you tried watching the extensions you have installed? Perhaps one could be producing the issue.